# How can I programmatically confirm a form resubmission in a web browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBrowser` on my form and once the page is loaded and some content is extracted, I call [`Refresh()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txewax99%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method but I'm getting this error from page:

[image]

How can I confirm this resubmission automatically and programmatically?

Note on buttons' text translation:

> Repetir = Repeat
>   Cancelar = Cancel

Comment: Use Post-Redirect-Get.

Comment: I don't own the page. How it works?

Comment: if you don't own the page then how are you expecting to fix the code..? I am confused here..

Comment: note that I'm using the WebBrowser control... I would fix it using something like WIN32API's `SendMessage()`. I'm just looking for the more elegant/easier approach

Comment: really hard to tell what you are doing when we can see what code you are currently using..

Comment: Loading a page on WebBrowser is what I'm doing. When I refresh the page it show that warning.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, try doing an AJAX post and checking on the response.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply change the URL in the WebBrowser to the same page, rather than refreshing?

If all you are doing is trying to load content, rather than actually displaying something - you could try Watin. http://watin.org/